# They organised a coup and once more took over the country. 'once more'

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning, idioms

> They organised a coup and once more took over the country.

'once more' : once more/once again (https://www.ldoceonline.com/ko/dictionary/once-more-once-again)

a) again, after happening several times before
I looked at myself in the mirror once more.
Once again she’s refusing to help.

b) used to say that a situation changes back to its previous state
The crowds had all gone home and the street was quiet once more.

c) formal used before you repeat something that you said before
Once again, it must be stressed that the pilot was not to blame.

What does 'once more' mean in the exmaple sentence? They had taken over the country in the past and once again took over the country, so they'd taken over the country two times before?

Comment: 'Once more' means 'again', not 'for the second time'.

Comment: They had been in charge of the country at least once before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You give three senses for the phrase *once more*. In

> They organised a coup and once more took over the country.

**(b) is the relevant sense**: they had control of the country at some point in the past, then lost that control before gaining it back *once more*. It is possible that the group in question had had control of the country several times before this coup, but this is not implied by the phrase *once more*.

In short: In this sentence *once more* is a stand-in for *again*.